# Given that a patient survived, what is the probability that the patient was categorized as serious upon arrival?

Tags: probability

Upon arrival at a hospital's emergency room, patients are being categorized according to their condition as critical, serious or stable. In the past year:

1. $10\%$ of the emergency room patients were critical
2. $30\%$ of the emergency room patients were serious
3. $60\%$ of the emergency room patients were stable
4. $40\%$ of the critical patients died
5. $10\%$ of the serious patients died, and
6. $1\%$ of the critical patients died

Given that a patient survived, what is the probability that the patient was categorized as serious upon arrival?

Can you help me with this question. This is a question about conditional probability but I don't know how to approach it.

Comment: Is anyone interest in this problem? Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

We have to calculate $P(\text{serious}\,|\,\text{survived})$. This can be written as the fraction $$\frac{P(\text{serious and survived})}{P(\text{survived})}$$. Similarly, we have $$90\%=P(\text{survived}\,|\,\text{serious})=\frac{P(\text{survived and serious})}{P(\text{serious})}=\frac{P(\text{serious and survived})}{30\%}$$ From this, we conclude that $P(\text{serious and survived})= 27\%$.

To calculate $P(\text{survived})$, we first write this as a sum on all possibilities $$P(\text{survived})=P(\text{survived and stable})+P(\text{survived and serious})+P(\text{survived and critical})$$ and to each possibility, we proceed as before. For example, $$99\%= P(\text{survived}\,|\,\text{stable})=\frac{P(\text{survived and stable})}{P(\text{stable})}=\frac{P(\text{survived and stable})}{60\%}$$ gives $P(\text{survived and stable})= 59,4\%$.